Ionic Appflow Apple Silicon build stack fails, but non-Apple Silicon build stack succeeds
I'm using the CI/CD pipeline called "Appflow" which is provided by the Ionic group.
I'm using an enterprise distribution iOS certificate, and in AppFlow, when I choose the latest NON-Apple Silicon build stack, my iOS build works perfectly.
But, when I choose the latest “Apple Silicon” build stack, my iOS build fails with the error shown below. What could explain why a build stack that uses the Apple Silicon build stack seems to think that my enterprise iOS distribution certificate is a "development" profile type, when (I think) is should be either "enterprise" or "production".
The ONLY difference is the build stack, which means that the provisioning profile, .p12, and everything else to build for iOS is valid.
The bundle identifier and profile name shown below are not the real ones. Edited for S.O. posting purposes.
There seems to be a mismatch between your provided export_method in gym
and the selected provisioning profiles. You passed the following options:
export_method: enterprise

Bundle identifier: com.test.app
Profile name: Test App
Profile type: development

Make sure to either change the export_method passed from your Fastfile or CLI
or select the correct provisioning profiles by updating your Xcode project
or passing the profiles to use by using match or manually via the export_options hash

